# How to insert missing sequence of rows in a dataset using if-else condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to insert missing sequences of data rows in a dataset using if-else conditions and appended the completed row count of the dataset into a new list.

Tried using multiple if-else conditions and nested if-else conditions to achieve the expected output but not able to get the correct dataset expected output.

Are there any other options to achieve the expected output without using if-else conditions or the nested if-else conditions?

My code below:

```
year = 2016
month = 2
day = 3
rainAmount = 0.2
rainList = []

for y in range(2015,2017):
    if y == year:
        for m in range(1,3):
            if m == month:
                for d in range(1,4):
                    if d == day:
                        newRain = rainAmount
                    else:
                       newRain = 0
                   rainList.append([y,m,d,newRain])
for r in rainList:
    print(r)
```

Expected output:

```
[year,month,day,newRain]

[2015,1,1,0]
[2015,1,2,0]
[2015,1,3,0.2]

[2015,2,1,0]
[2015,2,2,0]
[2015,2,3,0.2]

[2016,1,1,0]
[2016,1,2,0]
[2016,1,3,0.2]

[2016,2,1,0]
[2016,2,2,0]
[2016,2,3,0.2]
```

Actual output:

```
[2016,2,1,0]
[2016,2,2,0]
[2016,2,3,0.2]
```

Comment: Are you sure that days such as `2015-12-31` and `2016-01-31` are not in the expected output?

Comment: No. The above is just an example to sample for 3 days only in 2  respective months between years 2015 and 2016. My actual dataset time period is much bigger than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using list comprehension.

```
result  = [[y, m, d,  0.2 if d == 3 else 0 ] for y in range(2015,2017) for m in range(1,3) for d in range(1,4)]
for i in result:
    print(i)
```

Output

```
[2015, 1, 1, 0]
[2015, 1, 2, 0]
[2015, 1, 3, 0.2]
[2015, 2, 1, 0]
[2015, 2, 2, 0]
[2015, 2, 3, 0.2]
[2016, 1, 1, 0]
[2016, 1, 2, 0]
[2016, 1, 3, 0.2]
[2016, 2, 1, 0]
[2016, 2, 2, 0]
[2016, 2, 3, 0.2]
```

[List Comprehensions in Python](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)

Comment: Just need to add the additional conditions for month and year. The 0.2 is only on the last entry. `0.2 if (d == 3 and m == 2 and y == 2016) else 0`

Comment: Thank you for sharing this solution. It helps me very much to proceed to the next step.

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere I thought he miswrite the expected output.

Comment: What if I want to add in one more condition? E.g. for m in range(1,13) if m !=2 d in range(1,32) else d in range(1,29). Is it possible to add additional conditions in list comprehension? Thanks.

Comment: @MSDCLIMO that would be `result = [... for d in (range(1,32) if m!=2 else range(1,29))]`

Answer (score 0):

If you need date comparisons and other related functionalities, it might be better to represent the dates as [date objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) rather than integer lists. The [calendar package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html) provides functions for iterating over dates.

Answer (score 0):

The expected output you wanted,

```
year = 2016
month = 2
day = 3
rainAmount = 0.2
rainList = []

rainList = [[y, m, d, 0.2 if y == 2016 and m == 2 and d == 3 else 0] for y in range(2015, 2017) for m in range(1, 3) for d in range(1, 4)]
for r in rainList:
    print(r)
```

Output

```
[2015, 1, 1, 0]
[2015, 1, 2, 0]
[2015, 1, 3, 0]
[2015, 2, 1, 0]
[2015, 2, 2, 0]
[2015, 2, 3, 0]
[2016, 1, 1, 0]
[2016, 1, 2, 0]
[2016, 1, 3, 0]
[2016, 2, 1, 0]
[2016, 2, 2, 0]
[2016, 2, 3, 0.2]
```